# Is there any way to call application specific properties files from the weblogic manage server location?

Tags: java, jboss, weblogic

To load different application specific properties files from different manage servers in Jboss, there is an option to call the application specific properties file using:

```
System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir");
```

Is there any way to load different different properties files from different managed servers in weblogic?

There is batch configured in the application source code which needs to be run from only one manage server.

Comment: I imagine in JBoss you set the system property with a JVM property like -Djboss.server.config.dir=...
You can do it the same way in WebLogic Server.

Comment: No such configuration made. It is JBoss Default property. Can you please suggest if any property is also present for Weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

Is it application specific properties files you are loading? Can you let me know what property file you are trying to load?

Comment: I'm trying application related properties files [application binaries]